# How to disable the orange circle effect when clicking on a link, in a WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm trying to catch the mouse click location so I wrote an `onClick` in the `body` tag, but every time I click on the page the whole page turn orange for a little while.  Is there any setting can disable this effet?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [this](http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/3a6982b93a2d648e?pli=1) thread you can override the default orange outline by overriding

`-webkit-tap-highlight-color`

with

`-webkit-tap-highlight-color:  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);`

in your css file (you'll need to create a css file and add this if you currently don't have one).  The last value of 0 sets the alpha value to effectively render the color invisible (1 being fully visible).  If that's not the exact css style you're looking for you can poke around the other webkit styles to find similar declarations.

Props to Joe McCann for the idea.

Comment: it doesnt work with android 4.0.4 - anybody has experienced the same? (it works on previous versions and 4.1)

Comment: I was looking this in order to using it on webviews on Android devices.

Works like a charm :) 

+1 ;)

Answer (score 4):

McStretch answer is correct. Webkit on Android is compiled with this property set to orange, using the css you can override this.

Paste the following in your css:

```
* {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

(sorry, don't know how to add this as a comment to that answer)

Answer (score -2):

function mouseclick(  ) {
  var locString = "X = " + window.event.screenX + " Y = " + window.event.screenY;
  alert(locString);
}

you can use this function to catch mouseclick location

Comment: I know return the `event.pageX,event.pageY` can get the click location in Android's WebView, but still no way to avoid the boring orange rectangle..