# Phonegap yellow highlight

Tags: cordova

I have a Samsung Captivate. Whenever I click on a button or image a yellow highlight shows up around it. I was wondering is this the phone itself? Or is it something I can turn off via PhoneGap.

Makes the app ugly ;)

Thanks

Comment: For casual readers, "Samsung Captivate" is one of the US brand-names for the Galaxy S.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use -webkit-tap-highlight-color in your CSS.

See this answer as well: [How to disable the orange circle effect when clicking on a link, in a WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078018/how-to-disable-the-orange-circle-effect-when-clicking-on-a-link-in-a-webview)

Answer (score 0):

If you view the page in the browser on the device do you get this same effect?

Do you get this when viewing websites on the device?

If yes to the above then you may be able to control this with CSS.

Comment: Yes I do get the same on websites.Funny I have had this phone for a month and have never browsed a website. But yeah I get the same highlight.

Comment: Just to note when I do click on the image a yellow highlight goes over the whole image.

Answer (score 0):

```
button, li , a, *:hover 
{
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) !important;
}
```

above code did the trick for US.